# Different conditions for two UITextField in same View

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have two `UITextFields`in the same view and I'd like each one to have specific conditions. The first one need to accept only `42` characters long strings and the second one can accept `0123456789` and `.` only.

I used `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` to set the first textfield up but how can I set the second one without both having both conditions?

**TextFields :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
```

**First TextField condition:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
    return newLength == 42
}
```

**Second TextField condition ?**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:".0123456789").inverted
    let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
    let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
    return string == numberFiltered
}
```

I can't use `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` twice so can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simple like

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
 if textField == firstTextField{ // its Identify your textfield
   guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
 return newLength == 42
 }else{
  let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:".0123456789").inverted
let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
return string == numberFiltered
 }
return true
}
```

Comment: Woah I feel like the noob that I am haha, thank you very much!

Comment: FYI - there is no need for the `guard`. The `text` property of `UITextField` will never return `nil`. It's one of those cases where force-unwrapping the optional is perfectly safe.